# Create Flow condition: If column "End_date" is less than 7days from column "Start_Date", then

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, flow, power-automate, if-condition

I have two "Date & Time" type columns:

**Start_date**
and
**End_date**

I would like to create a manual triggered Flow (already have button writen in JSON in place) that compares them and:

if **End_date** is less than one week from **Start_date**, I would like to e.g e-mail to be sent (an action after is not priority, I would like to check that condition in the first place).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add condition like below:

```
formatDateTime(addDays(<StartDate>,7),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

is greater than

```
<EndDate>
```

Replace `<StartDate>` & `<EndDate>` with your actual dates selected from dynamic content of above actions.

**Similar question**: [Flow with Date Condition](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Flow-with-Date-Condition/td-p/334805)